Web browsers and browser-based apps keep crashing on my pc, regardless the OS
I had to buy a second hand PC with urgency. This desktop pc is presenting an odd behavior: Firefox hangs very often, sometimes the whole app and sometimes individual tabs. Also, I've observed several (presumed) browser-based apps hang aswell (e.g. Zoom, Pcloud when the settings window is open, etc.) but here is the odd thing: it happens on Windows partition, as well as on my debian partition. There must be some aspect of hardware that web browsers use more than other software, which causes these to hang with more likelihood.
I assume there has to be a hardware issue. I've ran OCCT few times (about an hour each time) and memtest86, and hardware shows perfect stability and integrity on those tests. Temperatures are also quite low in general, even throughout stress tests. The components seem all to be quite new.
Below I will keep a journal of my attempts and results:

Each OS is installed on a separate HDD, which rules out hard disk issues, unless both would have issues. Debian has detected bad sectors on it's installation drive.

Windows OS would show me BSOD somewhat often, but that stopped happening after updating. Debian on rare occasions force-logged me out too.

I couldn't/didnt' know how to switch to integrated graphics. Upon removing the discrete card, the on-board hdmi port displays nothing.

Debian suddenly decided to shut down out of the blue; it didn't just power off, it shot down correctly


In your experiences, what tests should I perform to rule out most common issues? If debian decides to shut down, where I could find a log entry for the reason?
below the hardware specs of the PC in question
   Processor    AMD Ryzen 5 3600X 6-Core
   Processor                3.80 GHz 
   Installed RAM    16,0 GB 
   Ram 1:
    Module Manufacturer:    Kingston
    Module Part Number: KF3600C17D4/8GX 
   Ram 2:
    Module Manufacturer:    Kingston
    Module Part Number: KF3600C17D4/8GX 
   Graphics:
    Device Name:    GIGABYTE Radeon R9 270X Windforce 3X OC
    Original Device Name:   ATI/AMD Radeon R9 270X (CURACAO XT)
    Device Class:   VGA Compatible Adapter 
   HDDs:
    WDC WD10EZEX-00BN5A0
    WDC WDS480G2G0B-00EPW0



depending on the browser, I wonder if turning off hardware acceleration would ne a starting point?

I would suggest that you perform hardware diagnostics and stress testing. Similar issues generally suggest similar causes, and when the OS is different, that leaves the hardware as the most likely culprit. Testing and replacing memory is one of the easier and least expensive things to try.

Thanks, @music2myear, but I've already tested processor and ram with memtest86 & occt and no issues show up! what other way I could test?

First thing, if you've not yet done so, is to run the latest LTS Debian, Ubuntu or other OS from USB, eliminating all hardware except main drive as possible culprit. If that works, it's either software/OS related or SSD/HDD failure.

Excellent idea, @DrMoishePippik. I am afraid that HDDs are the only thing I can boot the pc without - so I hope those are the culprit!

@DrMoishePippik on ubuntu live disk, there were no browser crashes, but installer crashes .. I installed ubuntu on a new HDD and removed the old ones, it's working a bit more stable than before, but still with an insane amount of crashes
